Mapping a Junction Table of a Subclass In Spring Boot JPA Not Working
I have a "Person" class and a "Film" class. The "TvShow" class is a subclass of "Film."
When I mapped a junction table, "Casts" for Person and Film, it worked fine, here is an example:
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
...
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
 private Set<Cast> cast;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "film_cast")
public class Cast {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CastId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("personId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;


    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("filmId")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "film_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "film_type")
    })
    private Film film;
   ...
}


@Embeddable
public class CastId implements Serializable  {

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "film_id")
    private FilmId filmId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Film {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "film")
    private Set<Cast> cast;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class FilmId implements Serializable  {

    @Column(name = "film_id")
    private Integer filmId;

    @Column(name = "film_type")
    private Integer filmType;
    ...
}


The above implementation works and did not give me an error, now if I try to replicate that but using the subclass "TvShow" I get an error when I want to map it to "Created." (Only TvShow has a created which is why its limited to that class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "film_created")
public class Created {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CreatedId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("personId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("tvShowId")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "film_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "film_type")
    })
    private TvShow tvShow;
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class CreatedId implements Serializable  {

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "tv_show_id")
    private FilmId tvShowId;
   ...
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tv_show")
public class TvShow extends Film {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvShow", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Created> created;
...
}


This is the error that I get:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate
SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: identifier mapping has wrong number of columns: com.name.project.model.Created type: component[personId,tvShowId]
I am puzzled about what is wrong because I did the exact same implementation as the above example, yet I'm getting an error about having the wrong number of columns.
